# Using set -e and traps in shell scripts

Tags: bash, shell, error-handling

I am trying to write a shell script that essentially calls a bunch of functions in another script.
The script looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

function cleanup() {
   exitStatus=$?
   if [ $exitStatus -ne 0 ]; then
      rm -rf /tmp/alpha*
   fi
   exit $exitStatus
}

trap cleanup ERR

VAR1="test"

. /home/common/scripts/utils.sh

echo "Executing function1"
function1 $VAR1

echo "Executing function2"
function2 $VAR1

exit $?
```

My question is that do I need to set -e as well as trap in order to make sure that my script is robust here or just using trap is enough.

Second: If I set -e in this script then do I need to set -e in `utils.sh` too in order to make sure that the function is executing correctly in that script or the set -e in this script will take care of that?

Answer (score 1):

`set -e` just exits the script immediately if there is an error, instead of continuing.  Whether or not to use it depends on the behaviour you want.

The `trap` just handles the error on exit, so if you're concerned about robustness the combination of the two is probably good.

You should put `set -e` in each sub-script if you want them to terminate immediately on error too.

Comment: I can replicate the behaviour of exiting the script by adding `exit $?` in my cleanup function too right? In that case I wouldn't need to use `set -e` right?

Comment: If I have put `set -e` in a sub-script and if there is an error in that sub-script will it exit from the main script too? (Assuming that I have put `set -e` in the main script)

Comment: `set -e` triggers your trap/cleanup function immediately if any of the commands in the script fail.  Otherwise the trap/cleanup happens on script exit.  And yes if the top script has `set -e` then a failed sub-script will cause the top script to exit

Comment: In my script I shouldn't really be having that `if` statement within the `cleanup()` function. I mean the only time that function will be invoked is when I will have a non zero exit code